# Are Components best practice to break the code in controller CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, controller

I am developing a web application using CakePHP. The flow of my application is as follows:

- A file is uploaded form view.
- Controller receives the file. Now depending of the type of the file I do different kind of processing. but eventually the parameters extracted are same and saved to same table in database. While doing processing for each type of file my controller became very lengthy. I saw some posts [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/0_P2bG13l58) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/FESG4oc1_5I) that encourages to use `component` but from the [cakebook](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/994/Introduction) it says to use components when you want to share code among different controllers which I am guessing it is utility type of class.

My question is how can I break my `controller` code maybe in among different files so that upon receiving a particular type of file in my controller I can redirect my flow?

Answer (score 1):

Processing uploads is data processing and should go by this into a model. I personally do not think all these component solution out in the wild are the right place for it.

If you move your upload processing into the model you can have your single controller and do all the checks in a model method that then can call associated models or get an instance of the model that will finally deal with your kind of file you want to be treated by that model.

Feel free to take a look at my [FileStorage](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) plugin. Read the readme.md it might give you some more ideas about proper file handling. IMO a file should never be attached directly to a record by just saving the path in for example Users.avatar, but instead the file should be associated to the user Model: User hasOne Avatar. Handling of the files and doing things with them is a lot easier then and you have a unified handling of all files.

Comment: Thanks. But I am under impression that you should call model from controller when you need to interact with database. So after I receive  a file via `POST` I extract useful information in controller and save the records in database by calling model.

Comment: That is wrong. A controller should just act like a conductor while your models would be the musicians who actually process the data (instructions from the conductor). Models are *not* exclusively thought for databases but for any kind of data processing. The benefits are clear: You can for example simply change the storage backend of our model by changing its data source. Models are easier to test than controller code, the code is more re-useable than in a controller. You can use it from a shell for example.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this. So do you mean should I show my view by url: `server:/model/methodname` or by `server:/controller/methodname`?

Comment: Get started by doing the blog tutorial if you struggle with the basics. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html You can not call a model from the URL, that would break the whole idea of MVC. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html Try IRC freenode #cakephp for community help by chat. The comments here are not the best place for a discussion.

Comment: I see what are you saying. But if I move my all processing to my model then wouldn't model code be too long? Then how would I break code for model?

Comment: Put the code specific to each kind of file in the related model? I don't know your app and goal so I can't tell you. And why do you worry even about code length? This tells it all: http://www.mikebernat.com/images/cake/layercake.png